# How do I get a hyperlink open only one internet explorer window

Tags: microsoft-excel, internet-explorer, hyperlink

How do I get a hyperlink open only one Internet Explorer window? It keeps opening the same thing from the link but in two IE windows.

Comment: Look in your IE settings.

Comment: I did but I am not finding anything.

Comment: are you double-clicking the link?

Comment: no I click on the cell and it opens two IE windows for the link

Answer (score 1):

Under internet options select this:

[image]

Select the option I have the arrow pointing to.